# Contentful new field wont show in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am currently working on a project on Gatsby/React with Contentful. Here is my problem: I need a new field in one of my models.

I added the new field via Contentful and recompiled the development bundle, but when I try to use the data from that field, I can not access it. I checked the `generated/graphql-types.ts` file to make sure the field is there but it is not. Then I checked the `http://localhost:8000/__graphql` IDE and I can see the new field that I added.

Here is the picture of it:

[image: http://localhost:8000/__graphql]

I also checked the google developer tools but the new field is also not there:

[image: google dev tools]

I cleared the cache and checked the fields in Contentful but can't seem to make the field appear. What should I do?

Comment: Silly question. Is your new field published in Contentful?

Comment: Of course it is published